# GeckoFx 29.0 version doesn't support web page using angularjs. Error message "angular is undefined"

Tags: angularjs, geckofx

I am creating Browser using `geckoWebBrowser` using `C#`. Here in my form.cs file code is working fine for normal sites but, if I open any websites which is using angularjs. It does not work and I got  message "angular is undefined".

For Example https://angularjs.org/

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://" + textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    }
}
```

Have someone seen this compatibility issue with Angular using GeckoFX 29.0?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for geckofx 29 version and xulrunner 29 version.It is not compatible for javascript,jquery and angularjs.Please go for geckofx v45.0.22.0 with firefox "xul" compatibility.It is working fine in my windows application.
              Thank you